# Writing tests for code that takes files as input

Tags: ruby, xml, testing, tdd, acceptance-testing

I'm writing a program right now that parses epub files (which is basically a zip with some xml metadata files). The program works great for all input files I tested it with.

Nontheless I'd like to write some tests (unit test or behavioral) to make sure it works with *all* files and to have "better code".

Is the only way to do this perfectly (on an at least theoretical level) to implement the EPUB specs and provide some XML snippets to tests?

I'm familiar with testing in general but I've never implemented tests for things that take files as their input, so I'm looking for more information about that too. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what exactly you are trying to ask here. Could you ask a more specific question?


"to make sure it works with all files" 

in order to do this your best bet is to make a correctness argument using the code or some formal logic! 

As Dijkstra famously said, "Program testing can be used to show the presence of bugs, but never to show their absence!" ;-)

Comment: Your suggestion basically is: Provide some basic EPUB files and test functionality like extracting the title, right? I know for sure that it works with these files then but not for sure that it does with others. I'm basically wondering what to test when I implement a parser based on a specification like EPUB. All in all it seems to be a question of XML selectors and crafting them according to the specification. Things that don't work are not valid. Thanks for you input, already.

Comment: Yes, the function for extracting title can be tested using a small fixture. And the same for various small, highly cohesive functions that you design (i.e. better code). You would then presumably compose these functions to achieve the goal of parsing the whole thing with the confidence that each small function works as expected. You can then make a stronger claim regarding correctness of the whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit testing approach is to eliminate external dependencies in tests.  That way, running the tests doesn't require your environment to do anything other than host your test program.

Inside your code, for the most part you should not be interested in "testfile.epub".  That's the job only of the OpenEpubFile() routine.  Instead, you are interested in testing the specific logic of "here is a pointer to some data, how do I unzip it?" or "how do I process a title tag?"  So your unit tests would provide sample zipped data to test how your unzip logic works, and sample title tags to see how your logic handles titles.  You'd pass it titles that are just fine, very long, very short, malformed, you'd present the different kinds of data required to exercise whatever logic you need to test in your code. But that data doesn't have to come from a file every single time, it can come from a test harness.

If your find your logic is hard to test, it's probably a sign that it's time to modularize it.  You need to separate out code that opens the file from the code that reads the data.  You need to separate the code that reads the data from the code that unzips the data.  You need to separate the code that unzips the data from the code that parses the XML.  You need to separate code that constructs the screen from code that paints the screen.  The Extract Method refactoring process will be very helpful here, as well as Rename Method.  And you'll become heavily dependent on the Dependency Inversion pattern.

Every time you can break it down into stateless code that implements pure logic, you can test just those rules very easily.  Better, as you break it into the needed modules, you'll find that adding new modules to handle the new cases becomes easier as you can repeat your existing patterns.

Yes, at some point you're going to have one test that assures you that your open() statement can actually open a file.  After you have the unit tested code passing all your tests, then it's time to move to integration testing.  That's where you can feed it a real set of .epub files and see the output is as desired.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reimplement .epub just for testing.

Create some tiny .epub files to show off certain traits, and create tests against those.